# stream type sockets to exchange objects using serialization?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, types, stream

I am studying exam questions and I am wondering how to go about the following question

Write a Java application that uses Stream type sockets to exchange Java Objects 
 using object serialisation. The client side should connect to the server and send it 
 an Integer Object. The server should print out this value and respond to the client 
 with a text based response encapsulated in a String Object. The client should 
 receive the String Object from the server and print out this response.

I have some ideas but I am not sure how to put it all together.. I am wondering if anyone knows of a sample I could refer to or had any code themselves. Sorry I am new here and maybe i am asking too much.
Thanks alot for reasing eitherway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up java.net.Socket and ServerSocket, and java.io.ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream and Serializable, and find the Custom Networking trail of the Java Tutorial.